# After Stack, line series is still overlapped with each other

Tags: teechart

I am using stack feature of Lineseries of teechart to plot series on top of each other. All series is having its own custom axis.

Even after stack, series are getting overlapped with each other. Each point of each series is stacked according to the logic of stack, but still series are getting overlapped with each other.

If require then I can share test Application as well.

Before Stack:
[image]

After Stack:
[image]